# MySQL - Query records between yesterday and today but with a specific time

Tags: mysql, date

I seem to be having a case of the Fridays. I am new to MySQL (few weeks now) and I just can't seem to get a report automated. I need to be able to query data from yesterday 8 am until today 8 am. I am going to schedule the report to run at 10 am. What is the best way to do this? I have been running it manually with BETWEEN but this will not do. I tried to use the interval feature but no luck. I think I am almost there.

One try:

```
purchase_date BETWEEN '2020-11-18 09:00:00' and (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 16 hour)
```

Another try:

```
purchase_date BETWEEN BETWEEN (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 40 hour) and (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 16 hour)
```

If you can just point me to the function or best option in this case, I should be able to figure out the arguments. Ideas/suggestions/thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE `CURDATE()` and `INTERVAL`

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 8 HOUR, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

RESULT

```
# CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 8 HOUR  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
2020-11-19 08:00:00                             2020-11-20 08:00:00
```

Comment: You rock!!! I tweaked it to be part of my where clause and it fetches the data beautifully. BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) and (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR)

Comment: I just tried to up vote your answer but it says I do not have enough points of some sort. I wanted to say thank you! This query was driving me bonkers.

Comment: you need 15 rep to upvote, but i am glad that your problem is solved.